# where can I find iOS 7 simulator?

Tags: simulator, ios7, xcode5

I have downloaded the xcode5_GM_seed and install it, but I cannot find iOS7 simulator in components.

Where can I find iOS 7 simulator?

Answer (score 30):

XCode 5 comes with iOS 7 sdk and simulator automatically. However, since iOS 7 is *not* supported in old "iPhone" and supported in "**iPhone Retina**..." and "iPad.." so you need to select appropriate iOS simulator in your project... (your old/existing projects seems to be selecting to "iPhone" simulator)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Since iOS 7 does not support non-retina devices, you need to select one of the retina devices to see iOS7 simulator option.

Answer (score 7):

If you can't find a simulator version you're looking for, chances are that you need to download it from the components section. Navigate to **Preferences → Downloads** and make sure you download all the simulator builds that you may need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode preferences > downloads. But until the OS is released, you will need a paid ios developer account.

Comment: Ios 7 has now been released. I've upgraded to Xcode 5 but there is still no ios 7 simulator. I'm not an iOS developer, I just test websites. Do I have to purchase an ios developer membership anyway?

Comment: Was being an idiot. iOS7 simulator isn't showing in the download list, but is installed by default. Got my answer when I launched the simulator. #embarrassing

Comment: It should totally say "installed" in that list, I came here wondering if I needed to upgrade to Mavericks to get it hahaha

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 6:
In iOS Simulator, go to Hardware | Device | Manage Devices...
Click the + in the bottom left and choose whatever Simulator you want.